# Update input UI when calling Shiny.setInputValue

Tags: r, shiny

Consider this sample shiny application. You can type in a car name like "Valiant" and it will print out the MPG value from the `mtcars` built-in data set. I also wanted to allow the user to click on a car rather than type it. I did this by generating a list of links with car names and writing a bit of javascript to call `Shiny.setInputValue` when the link is clicked.

I noticed that when a link is clicked, the server state updates (ie the `textOutput("MPG")` value changes) but the text box doesn't update to show the current value. Is there a different way to get the value such that the `textInput` is updated AND the reactive `textOutput` is updated?

```
library(shiny)

script <- "$(document).on('click', '.name-opt a', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); Shiny.setInputValue('name',this.dataset.name);
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
  textInput("name", "Name:"),
  textOutput("MPG"),
  uiOutput("carlist")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$carlist <- renderUI({
    tags$ul(
      Map(function(v) tags$li(tags$a(v, href="#", "data-name"=v)), rownames(head(mtcars, 20))), 
      class="name-opt")
  })
  output$MPG <- renderText({
    req(input$name)
    paste(input$name, "mpg:", mtcars[input$name,]$mpg)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Tested with `shiny_1.5.0`

Comment: You can trigger the update from some JS code; but I'm sure you know that, so I'm not sure to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent. It seems like `Shiny.setInputValue` should be updating the value in the HTML text input, but it does not. Is there another function that triggers the UI to update?

Comment: `$("#name").val(this.dataset.name)`, I think.

Comment: `Shiny.setInputValue` only sets a value to the `input` object (as demonstrated by your app). The method to update the value of a widget is specific to each widget.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent In some cases, it would be very useful if both the input value and UI could be updated without having to know which type of update* function to use to change the input value. For example, if you have a large set of varied inputs and you just want to create an identical set of inputs with incremented inputIds.

Comment: `session$sendInputMessage(inputId, list(value = your_value))` works for many inputs but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Serverside: You have to make a reactive value, here: `myinput`, and then call its value with myinput(). Then you need observer that fires the `updateTextInput` whenever `myinput()` changes

```
 myinput = reactive({
    paste(input$name)
  })
  
  observeEvent(myinput(),{
  updateTextInput(session, "name", value = myinput())
  })
```

The whole code:

```
library(shiny)

script <- "$(document).on('click', '.name-opt a', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); Shiny.setInputValue('name',this.dataset.name);
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
  textInput("name", "Name:"),
  textOutput("MPG"),
  uiOutput("carlist")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$carlist <- renderUI({
    tags$ul(
      Map(function(v) tags$li(tags$a(v, href="#", "data-name"=v)), rownames(head(mtcars, 20))), 
      class="name-opt")
  })
  output$MPG <- renderText({
    req(input$name)
    paste(input$name, "mpg:", mtcars[input$name,]$mpg)
  })
  
  myinput = reactive({
    paste(input$name)
  })
  
  observeEvent(myinput(),{
  updateTextInput(session, "name", value = myinput())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the `paste()` or the separate reactive element is needed. It seems like `observeEvent(input$name, updateTextInput(session, "name", value = input$name))` would be more direct. But I'm still surprised this needs to be done in the server code and not javascript when it's a client side UI update.

Comment: You are right. I just was glad to have an answer to the presented question.